# Extract SP and DDL Scripts in sybase Server

Tags: sql, sap-ase

How do I extract **DDL, Stored Procedures (SP)** and other database scripts from Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [**ddlgen** utility](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/CHDBBGGC.htm) included with sybase, ususally found in the Sybase Central directory, or the $SYBASE/ASEP/bin. This should be able to generate scripts to create all of the database objects including user-defined datatypes (UDD), indexes, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: Thanks Michael..But do u have any easy way like in sql server..i m new to sybase..

Comment: *ddlgen* **is** the easy way to extract database objects.  With minimal options, you can extract everything from the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sp_helptext](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1502/html/sprocs/X25756.htm) to show the DDL.

Comment: Yeah tried..But formatting is not proper with sp_helptext. Also any command available to extract DDL script ?