# DB2 command to get the table schema definition

Tags: db2

what is the DB2 command used to see the schema definition of a given table? I tried sp_help in db2 but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U'
```

where `U` is for user table.

Check this post to have a good understanding

[From a Sybase Database, how I can get table description ( field names and types)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429898/from-a-sybase-database-how-i-can-get-table-description-field-names-and-types)

**EDIT:**

Above mentioned is the best approach. Other than that you can use

[ddlgen Utility](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility204.htm)

Comment: Rahul, i am looking for a sybase system command used to see the table creation script. for example sp_help gives the details about the table. similarly i wnt to know the command for viewing the script

Comment: sorry this is not what I wanted. I want the name of system stored  procedure for viewing the ddl.I got the necessary command do it

Answer (score 1):

The `ddlgen` command can be used to extact all ddl information, into script form.  It's usually found in $SYBASE/ASEP/bin

Look at my answer here for more information:
[Extract SP and DDL Scripts in sybase Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081975/extract-sp-and-ddl-scripts-in-sybase-server/15094599#15094599)