# Sybase: Generate a script Between two SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update, sybase, sql-scripts, powerdesigner

I've a Sybase database where I will make a LOT of changes, and I would like to make my changes (currently using PowerDesigner 16), save it as .SQL then generate a .SQL to migrate my initial database to the new database structure.

I don't care about the data, I just want to update the structure with this script.

Any idea how to create this script?

**EDIT**: It has nothing to do with the given "duplicate", the other ticket is speaking on how to export the sql for SP/... In my case I only want the difference between the two sql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract SP and DDL Scripts in sybase Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081975/extract-sp-and-ddl-scripts-in-sybase-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have one, you can create a model from your initial database, with `File > Reverse Engineer > Database`.

Create a copy of this model with `File > Save As` (as type Archived PDM), say copy.apm.

Then modify the model as you wish.

Then use `Database > Apply Model Changes to Database`, using the option `Using an archive model` (select the above copy.apm), to generate the ALTER script.

Comment: I did only an initial test, but this seems to be EXACTLY what I need :) I feel dum to not have found this before :)

Answer (score 0):

Anybody looking for a program agnostic way of generating the DDL for a database could use the ddlgen program that comes with ASE

See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1572/html/utilityguide/CHDBBGGC.htm

So to create the DDL of database *pubs2*, you could do something like

```
ddlgen -Usa -Ppassword123 -SSERVERNAME -TDB -Npubs2 -Ooutput_file.sql
```