# How can I remotely connect with ddlgen

Tags: java, database-schema, remote-access, sap-ase

I have installed sybase ASE 15 in remote machine and now I am able to extract ddl of tables and other objects by using following commands:-

```
ddlgen -Usa -Ppassword  -SMachine-name -Dmaster -TU -Stable1 -Odef.master.mytitles.out
```

from this query I got script of create table.
Now I want to access ddlgen from another machine to getting the ddl of any table but it was showing following error in my command prompt

```
system can not find specified file path
```

Can anyone suggest me that how can I access ddlgen command remotely .

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 0):

`ddlgen`, and the libraries it uses are part of the Sybase ASE installation.  You will need to install the libraries on the local system, or RDP/RSH into the remote system and execute the commands there.

The utilities are located under `%SYBASE%\ASEP\bin` (Windows) or `$SYBASE/ASEP/bin`

There is not a way to directly access `ddlgen` executable from a remote system.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but please will  you give the ddlgen  libraries name or any link of libraries for install on other machine?

Comment: The utilities are included in the ASE Client Software CD, possibly the Open Server SDK.  On a Windows server, I think it might be in the `%SYBASE%\ASEP\bin` directory.  Please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081975/extract-sp-and-ddl-scripts-in-sybase-server/15094599#15094599) for the documentation link with more details